# Rest API iteration until number of records reached

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to get the api iteration until it pulls the whole records. Any idea/hits would be really appreciated.  it returns 5000 records default max per api call and there are almost 30000 rows in account object.

As per doc- more than 5000 records that can be fetched, pass another API call with Offset as 5001 so that remaining records (maximum 5000 records again) are fetched

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://xyzabc.com/account'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','Accesskey': '1234'}
body = {"select": [
"accountid",
"accountname",
"location"],
"offset" :0}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
account = response.json()
```

Comment: Something is missing in your payload or API configuration. As you do not specify what API you use, what is the legitimate payload structure and what policies the API vendor has, nothing can be said about how to configure it to return more records. You have to check your API's vendor, read the documentation and see there how to configure it so you'll be able to get more records. Also `"offset =0` is probably `"offset":0`, as it's a dictionary. That **offset** parameter may be what really matters, but once again nothing is known unless you specify how it's used in your API.

Comment: Thanks. Updated.It's and there is nothing more than offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your offset is *where* *you* *are*, you can do it in a loop like this:

```
url = 'https://xyzabc.com/account'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','Accesskey': '1234'}

# Please check if you have a better way to get total number from your API specs, 
# then specify it - that may need a separate API call.
total_records = 1000000000
# Get the results of your API calls into the list
accounts = []

# Go from 0 to total_records every 5000 records
try:
    for i in range(0, total_records, 5000):
        body = {"select": ["accountid",
                           "accountname",
                           "location"],
                           "offset" :i}
        response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
        accounts.append(response.json())
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Connection error - {e}") # Handle it your way

for account in accounts:
     # Your logic for every account fetched.
```

Comment: Thanks much. Total records is unknown though and it would be keep increasing as more accounts are added. This month its 30k, in 15 days it could be 35k

Comment: So you just give it a reasonably large number - **500000** or *1000000* and just process the error if API call fails. You will never go above some number, millions or billions, so you can use `total_records = 1000000000` for example.